# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap dropdown isn't working for me.  I did everything correctly as you can see it there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<title>Test site | Jony</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="Testing website coded by Jony - rapture-gfx" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"><script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script     src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script><!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">$(window).load(function() {      $('.flexslider').flexslider({    animation: "slide"  });});</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
</head>
<header>
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="current"><span style="color: #bde2e1;">Home</li>

<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Servers</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li class="hovering"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="hovering"><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
<li class="hovering"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</li>



<li class="hovering"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="hovering"><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
<li class="hovering"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bootstrap is a ready framework with features like grid system, rows, ready js menus and more.

There's an explanation of how it works:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns 
It doesn't work for me.

Yes, my `src` links correctly to the JS files.

Comment: You shouldn't add bootstrap js twice.

Comment: The menu doesn't pop up.

Comment: Try to alter the ``bootstrap-dropdown.js``. It works for me. But I DONT know why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your missing the `body` in your html.

put your script at the bottom of the page or after ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
</script>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rLL75/

EDIT:

use a newer version of jquery.

Comment: It's still doesn't work.
And I can't put the menu inside the body ?

Comment: @Jony: your missing a `<body>` tag. are you familiar with html & js?

Comment: Yes mate... I already have a body tag inside my HTML, body tag is placed under it there's my HTML:

http://pastebin.com/MChHWh5f

The menu just doesn't pop up on click.  I see everything is setup correctly.

Comment: @Jony: your peace of code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rLL75/1/ put the `header` into the body.

Comment: http://justxp.plutohost.net/testing/index.html this is my site, I put the header class inside the body and still doesn't work, you know what it does? it makes you go back to top. 

I also tried <header></header> inside the body, and still doesn't work. I really don't know whats wrong with the code. thanks once again!

Comment: well lets start with removing `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>` we don't need it twice (js/bootstrap.min.js is on the next line).

Comment: That didn't work, and yes I can try, could you please link me to a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-static header">
        <div class="navbar-inner container">
            <ul class="nav" role="navigation">
               <li class="brand"><span style="color: #bde2e1;">Home</span></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                   <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                   <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                       <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                       <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                       <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                       <li class="divider"></li>
                       <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="hovering"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
               <li class="hovering"><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
               <li class="hovering"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
           <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</header>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nope man , that just ruins my whole page + still doesn't work.